# automatically turning on usb mass storage when usb is connected

Tags: usb-mass-storage

Majority if not all times when I plug in my USB I want to use the USB Mass Storage functionality thus I was wondering there is a way to enable USB Mass Storage once a USB is connected.

Comment: Related: [Why can't I see Android storage as a partition on PC?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205559/218526)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Auto Mount Your SD Card](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrtstudio.automount) should do that for you:

> Automatically mount your SD card. Quit manually mounting your SD card every time you plug your phone into your computer.

I used that one one of my phones when I still connected it frequently via USB, and it did its job wonderfully. The app is available for free on the playstore, so nothing to lose :)