# How to Automatically Connect as MSD on Android 7.0

Tags: 7.0-nougat, usb-mass-storage

There is another [similar question for an older version](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/31850/automatically-turning-on-usb-mass-storage-when-usb-is-connected) of Android and [instructions here](https://www.addictivetips.com/android/how-to-set-the-default-usb-connection-type-in-android-6-0/) for Android 6.0 but neither work, plus I would like to have the entire phone connected, not just the MicroSDHC card.

**How can Android 7.0 be force to automatically connect as USB Mass Storage Device?**

*It would be nice to have solutions for both standard and rooted phone but mine is currently rooted.*

Right now, it is a pain since it automatically connects for charging and one must unlock the phone to get to the notification to open the list of options to select *Use USB to Transfer Files*. This is too much work as the only reason I am connecting the phone to a computer and not a charger is to get files.

Comment: _"but neither work"_ - Can you describe what happens when you change "Select USB Configuration" in developer options (currently available up to Android O) ?

Comment: @CzarMatt Nothing changes. When I connect the phone, it is still only connected for charging. That is what the notification says but I also tried anyway and there are no folders that appear. Changing it to MSD from there makes it show the phone contents.

Comment: What is the make/model of your phone ?

Comment: @CzarMatt - Lenovo Moto G5 but does it matter? Do these instructions for earlier versions of Android work on 7.0 for other phones?